# how to decode % in app

Tags: php, api, json

the % sign was not working on a shortcode-ui field on the website so i did:

```
attr.set( 'value', encodeURIComponent( decodeURIComponent( attr.get( 'value' ).replace("%", "&#37;") ) ), { silent: true } );
```

And it worked, but now on the site app i get "&#37"; instead of %. On that field for the API i have:

```
"text"    => urldecode( $breaking_news_text ),
```

And im changing it to:

```
"text"    => html_entity_decode( $breaking_news_text, ENT_QUOTES ),
```

But its not working. Any ideas how to solve this? thank you in advance.

Comment: how is it a wordpress specific question?